# Make a Scatter Plot in matplotlib with dates on x axis and values on y

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, statistics, scatter

I am having trouble making a scatter plot that has from a date array and a bunch of PM 2.5 values. My lists would look like the following:

```
dates = ['2015-12-20','2015-09-12']  
PM_25 = [80, 55]
```

Comment: plt.scatter(dates, PM_25) ??

Comment: If that doesn't work what's the error message? You may have to convert dates to date time. If u have pandas you can do [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

Comment: I'm getting this error: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2010-01-01

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ['2015-12-20','2015-09-12']  
PM_25 = [80, 55]
dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

plt.scatter(dates, PM_25, s =100, c = 'red')
```

`s` sets the size
`c` sets the color

There are a whole bunch of other args as well:
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter

Comment: This is great! Could I then make this more specific, giving months or even seasonal labels for each year?

Comment: When I try to make a scatterplot with `datetime` in the `x`-axis, I get `TypeError: invalid type promotion`. Your solution does not work.

Comment: I also got the `invalid type promotion` error like @dwanderson and @BCR. Changing the dates conversion to `dates = [d.to_pydatetime() for d in dates]` works for me.

Comment: @TiffanyG.Wilson and others having the invalid type of promotion error. Do this 
    plt.scatter(list(df.time.values),list(df.y.values),color='r')

Comment: @Apex Thanks. It worked by using your piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

If a plot with data that contains dates, you can use **[plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html)**

> Similar to the plot() command, except the x or y (or both) data is
>   considered to be dates, and the axis is labeled.

First convert list to date time, as @RSHARP showed,

```
dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]
```

then you can use plot_date

```
plt.plot_date(dates, PM_25, c = 'red')
```

Answer (score 1):

a pandas dataframe is more common usually. so it's efficient to me:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ['2015-12-20','2015-09-12']  
PM_25 = [80, 55]
data = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.to_datetime(dates),'PM_25':PM_25})
data.plot(x='dates',y='PM_25',marker='o',linestyle='none')
```

and you can define more like this:

```
data.plot(x='dates',y='PM_25',marker='o',linestyle='none',color='red',ms=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, after several updates in libraries lately other answers do not work.

Using @Apex we can get the following:

```
df = ...
plt.scatter(list(df.time.values),list(df.y.values),color='r')
```

In this case you may got the following error:

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ...
```

Basically, there is a check for the `datetime64[us]` type. If you convert data to this type upfront you will avoid the bugged code part in a library.

So the following code works fine currently:

```
df = ...
plt.scatter(list(df.time.astype('datetime64[us]').values),list(df.y.values),color='r')
```