# Python scatterplot vs plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use Python's `plt.scatter` or `ax.scatter` to show a car finishing times as scatterplot chart. So my x axis contains an array:

```
'car001','car002','car003', ...
```

The y axes should contain the finish time in datetime format like:

```
'2019-01-01 23:32:01','2019-01-01 23:32:01','2019-01-01 23:32:01', ...
```

Why it is so difficult to use datetime values as pandas dataframe with a scatterplot?
I don't want to use `plt.plot()` with linestyle 'o'.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256750/make-a-scatter-plot-in-matplotlib-with-dates-on-x-axis-and-values-on-y

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = ['2017-01-01 23:32:01','2018-01-01 23:32:01','2019-01-01 23:32:01']  
PM_25 = ['car001','car002','car003']
dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

plt.scatter(dates, PM_25)
plt.show()
```